# how to make the keyboard LED's blink using a linux driver?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, kernel, driver

Iam pretty new to linux driver development. Please post a code snippet which will illustrate the linux driver program to capture any keyboard press and that will make blink the capslk or scrllok or numlok led's. I am using ubuntu 3with kernel version 3.5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First post your code you have tried!

Comment: @haccks: sree did already state that s/he has zero understanding on the topic. So how could s/he even write a single line of code without knowing what to actually do, or where to look for information.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question. Somebody has a clear, specific task at hand (make input device LEDs blink by a program running under the Linux kernel). But this somebody has no idea where to look for information, which APIs to use. The downvotes are completely unaccounted for and closing the question as off-topic is unacceptable. This question can be answered perfectly fine.

Comment: @datenwolf; OK, voting up to compensate -ve votes..

Answer (score 1):

All the relevant info is found here in the Linux kernel source tree Documentation. Most importantly in [$KERNELSRC/Documentation/input/input.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/input.txt)

> ```
> 5. Event interface
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Should you want to add event device support into any application (X, gpm,
> svgalib ...) I <vojtech@ucw.cz> will be happy to provide you any help I
> can. Here goes a description of the current state of things, which is going
> to be extended, but not changed incompatibly as time goes:
>
> You can use blocking and nonblocking reads, also select() on the
> /dev/input/eventX devices, and you'll always get a whole number of input
> events on a read. Their layout is:
>
> struct input_event {
>   struct timeval time;
>   unsigned short type;
>   unsigned short code;
>   unsigned int value;
> };
>
> 'time' is the timestamp, it returns the time at which the event happened.
> Type is for example EV_REL for relative moment, EV_KEY for a keypress or
> release. More types are defined in include/linux/input.h.
>
> 'code' is event code, for example REL_X or KEY_BACKSPACE, again a complete
> list is in include/linux/input.h.
>
> 'value' is the value the event carries. Either a relative change for
> EV_REL, absolute new value for EV_ABS (joysticks ...), or 0 for EV_KEY for
> release, 1 for keypress and 2 for autorepeat.
> ```

The event codes are described in
[$KERNELSRC/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt)

There are special event codes for LEDs, and you can not only read from `/dev/event…` but also write to it, using the LED event codes to set the LED status.